# Inserting values to an empty multidim. numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to create an empty numpy array of a shape `(?, 10, 10, 3)`. `?` means I don't know how many elements will be inserted. Then I have many numpy arrays of a shape `(1, 10, 10, 3)` which I want to be inserted to the prepared array one by one, so the `?` mark will be increasing with inserted elements.

I'm trying all variations of numpy array methods like `empty`, `insert`, `concatenate`, `append`... but I'm not able to achieve this. Could you please give me a hand with this?

Comment: Don't do that; NumPy arrays are fixed-size, and trying to extend them dynamically requires making a new array every time, with horribly expensive, quadratic runtime costs.

Comment: If you have some idea on the max possible length along the first axis, simply pre-allocate with `out = (M,10,10,3)`, with `M` being that max number and index and assign at each iteration : `out[i] = ..` keeping the count of iterations. At the end, simply slice out `out[:C]` with `C`being that last iteration number/count.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. So I did it by removing the first single-dimensional entry of the inserted element, appended it to a regular python array and that made it a NumPy array. It works that way, not sure about effectiveness.

Comment: If you *really* have to do something like this, don't accumulate into an array, accumulate into a plain `list` object using `my_list.append(array_x)`, then, do `final_array = np.array(my_list)`

Comment: @T.Poe what do you mean by a "regular python array"? Do you mean a *list*?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes I meant a list, sry. I did it the way you suggested.

Comment: Are you just trying to create a 4 dimensional numpy array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`np.append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.append.html#numpy.append) works:

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.empty((0,10,10,3))

array = np.random.rand(1,10,10,3)

mat = np.append(mat, array, axis=0)
mat = np.append(mat, array, axis=0)

print(mat.shape)

>>>(2,10,10,3)
```

Comment: Thanks. But what about this "horribly expensive, quadratic runtime costs" as someone mentioned in the comments under the question? Is it true or not?

Comment: I believe it is. You'd be better off appending to a list and then form the array if you can. I was just answering your question!

Comment: Ok, so I just use the list list appending, thanks again.

Comment: If `mat` and `array` match in dimensions, I prefer to use `concatenate`.  `np.append` looks too much like `list.append`, confusing beginners in many ways.